# Android Equalizer not working in android 9 devices

Tags: android

I am working in Android equalizer all working fine in up to android 8 but not working in android 9 devices refer lib link is https://github.com/harjot-oberai/MusicDNA

Comment: Is there any error log or trace and so on ?

Answer (score 0):

Equalizer equalizer = new Equalizer(0,mediaplayer.getAudioSessionId());

equalizer.setEnabled(true);

equalizer.getNumberOfBands(); //it tells you the number of equalizer in device.

equalizer.getNumberOfPresets()

Comment: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b Error: -19